# Regex to match multi-character delimiter

Tags: php, regex

Given: a string with two or more substrings separated by " - " where the substrings can have spaces and dashes in them as long as they aren't that exact sequence.

How do I match all the substrings in PHP?

For example:

- "substring1 - substring2" matches "substring1" and "substring2"
- "sub-string- 1 - sub-string -2 - sub-string-3" matches "sub-string- 1", "sub-string -2", and "sub-string-3"

Thank you.

Comment: What is the logic by which `sub-string- 1` becomes `sub-string- 1` and not `1-sub-string -2` ?

Comment: The delimiter is the string " - ", so everything before the " - " gets matched, which is "sub-string- 1"

Comment: I want to know why you are choosing to use regex in this situation. You are clearly splitting on " - "

Comment: @geru *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which platform? PHP?

Comment: PHP. I'll try to add the tag.

Comment: So its not specifically regex you need to do this in? [phpdocs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Agreed, splitting is a solution. I want to use regex so someone could define their own match system if they don't like my delimiter string.

Comment: It is more difficult than I had originally supposed. I thought before I bolt on the regex and do a split I would check if there is a quick-easy solution I'm not seeing.

Comment: Please post some real world examples.

Comment: I have inventory item descriptions segmented with this sequence. For example: "derailleur hanger - OEM 4-part 2-dropout since mid-2016 alloy - Bacchetta" which is getting correlated with a SKU, in this case "DERH-OEM2-BAC". Because the SKUs can have different formats and taxonomies, I want to use a regex to have the flexibility to adapt for different SKU labelling situations. Sometimes, the model information will have additional tags.

Comment: @Worthy7 I think he need regex since he didn't want to split all `-`. _sub-string- 1 - sub-string -2 - sub-string-3" matches "sub-string- 1", "sub-string -2", and "sub-string-3_

Comment: @geru make some effort and if any error found, ask it here

Comment: This is what I thought should have worked: /(.*)((?= - )(.*))+/  I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to explode the string with `space`+`-`+`space`. It can be done without regex:

```
explode(" - ", $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/U0w7eG)

If you want to deal with any whitespace and any amount of it (1 or more), use a regex-based split:

```
preg_split('~\s+-\s+~', $s)
```

Here, `\s+-\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces, `-`, and 1+ whitespaces. To match any Unicode whitespace, add `u` modifier: `'~\s+-\s+~u'`. To match any dash, use `\p{Pd}`.

Comment: @Worthy7 said the same. And, I can't see any way to do this nicely with regex. So, marking as correct answer.

Comment: Glad I could help you anyway. If you think this answer is helpful, please also consider upvoting it.